# How to validate an email id using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to validate an email ID for a user from DB using javascript/jQuery. How can I do that ?

Comment: do you not mean email address?

Comment: Java and Javascript is not the same.

Comment: Suggestion: read about how to ask reasonable questions on stack overflow ( http://stackoverflow.com/help ). Hint: dropping requirements alone doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpfull:

```
function validateEmail($email) {
    var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
    return emailReg.test( $email );
}
```